# How do I convert json nested array to multidimensional arraylist in java?

Tags: java, json

I have a json object with a field like this:
"states" : [1,2,3,[1, 3, 5]]

I was wondering if there was cleaner way to convert it to multidimensional arraylist in java.

Comment: well, find a "object" that can have that structure... you either have to use `List<Object>`... or you have to treat the single elements are lists of 1 element with `List<List<Integer>>` (or look for `Variant` on google)

Answer (score 0):

Can try modifying below sample.

```
      ArrayList <String,List<Integer[]>> arr=new ArrayList<>();
     for(int i = 0; i<jobject.names().length(); i++){
           arr.add(jobject.names().getString(i),  
         Arrays.asList(jobject.get(jobject.names().getString(i))));
       }
```