# How do I convert a JSONArray to a multidimensional arraylist?

Tags: java, json

My code:

```
try {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body());
    List<JSONArray> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        arr.add(array.getJSONArray(i));
    }
    Log.d("arr",arr.toString());
}catch (JSONException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

This is my `arr`:

```
[["bdbd","hdhs","hdhd","1234567890","[[shhs, sbbs, married], [sjsn, snsn, unmarried]]"]]
```

I want to convert the last element inside my `arr`

> "[[shhs, sbbs, married], [sjsn, snsn, unmarried]]"

to a multidimensional ArrayList (`ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`). How do I do this?

Comment: Is this solution to your problem [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68386328/how-do-i-convert-json-nested-array-to-multidimensional-arraylist-in-java)

Comment: It's not valid JSON, so you may have to parse it by hand.

Comment: @shmosel How do I do that? Can you please guide me?

Comment: ChatGPT is good at this type of task.

Answer (score 0):

After finding no other solution, I just iterated over the whole string and appended each element to the arraylist like this:

```
String temp = arr.get(0).get(4).toString();
String details = "";
ArrayList<String> temp1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> final = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=2; i<temp.length()-1; i++){
    if(temp.charAt(i) != ',' && temp.charAt(i) != ' ' && temp.charAt(i) != '['){
        if(temp.charAt(i) != ']')
            details += temp.charAt(i);
        else{
            temp1.add(details);
            final.add(temp1);
            temp1 = new ArrayList<>();
            details = "";
        }
    }
    else{
        if(!details.equals("")) {
            temp1.add(details);
        }
        details = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a one liner solution. Don't use json.org library use Jackson Json library. In this case all you veed to do is

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
List<Object> myList = om.readValue(response.body(), List.class);
```

Also, there is a JsonUtil class that is a thin wrapper over ObjectMapper that allows you to do the same without instantiating ObjectMapper:

```
List<Object> myList = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(response.body(), List.class);
```

JsonUtils comes with MgntUtils OpenSource library written and maintained by me. You can get it as a [Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including javadoc and source code). Here is [Javadoc for JsonUtils class](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html)